# iTunesConnect App Name Confusion

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I've developed an iOS app and I am going to submit it to iTunes. I have to do the following things.

**Member Center**:

A. Create App ID 
B. Create Certificates (for this, I have to create CSR file from Key Chain Access)
C. Create Profiles

**iTunes**:

D. Create App in iTunes (on the first time iTunes asks for Company Name to display in iTunes)
E. Enter the details
F. Upload binary

So far I have done upto *STEP D*. For the *STEP B*, I have created a single the CSR file with my name as Common Name (not my Company name), and used it to create both development and distribution certificates. When I checked the certificates in Keychain Access, both the certificates show my name. I suspect the distribution profile should show my company name.

I have the following questions now.

- Will iTunes show the name in the Distribution certificate as the Company Name?
- Will iTunes show the name which I entered while I created the first app as Company Name?
- Is the way I created the distribution certificate correct? I can use same CSR file for all certificates?

Comment: Please NOTE: If you are going to down vote this question, please let me know. I'll delete this. :) Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to answer your questions, but I might be mistaken, since it's been 1 and 1/2 years since I did this.

> - Will iTunes show the name in the Distribution certificate as the Company Name?
> - Will iTunes show the name which I entered while I created the first app as Company Name?

iTunes showed as Company Name the detail we entered during creation of the first app.

The name in the Distribution Certificate may be shown as "Developer" field in iTunes App Store or "Seller" in the app page in http://itunes.apple.com/app/appID, but I'm not entirely sure about this. I think the name in our Distribution Certificate is similar to the Company Name we entered during creation of the first app, except for some spacing/capitalization stuff.

> - Is the way I created the distribution certificate correct? I can use same CSR file for all certificates?

If I also recall correctly, we also used the same CSR to create the Development and Distribution Certificates.